# How to prevent form submission while page reload in razor pages in ASP.NET Core 7 web app (without using MVC)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm trying to write a simple page with form in an ASP.NET Core 7 web app with Razor pages. I'm facing a problem while reloading that page.

The previous submission is happening again while reloading. How to prevent form submission while page reload in Razor pages (not MVC)?

In "classic" ASP.NET, I as able to use the `IsPostback` property to prevent these issues, but in Razor pages, I am unable to use it.

Comment: Could you  add some code showing what you did so far ? If you added minimal reproducible example, it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.

Comment: Use the Post-Redirect-Get pattern to prevent duplicate form submission: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the RedirectToPage method: In your POST handler, after processing the form submission, use the RedirectToPage method to redirect the user to the corresponding GET handler.

```
return RedirectToPage("Index");
```